# How do I remove an element from an array at a specified index but not do the operation in-place

Tags: arrays, ruby, element

Ruby 2.4.  I want to create a new array by removing an element at a specified index from an array.  I thought `delete_at` was the way, but it performs in-place and doesn't return the newly created array, but rather, the element that was removed:

```
2.4.0 :003 > a = ["a", "b", "c"]
 => ["a", "b", "c"]
2.4.0 :004 > a.delete_at(0)
 => "a"
2.4.0 :005 > a
 => ["b", "c"]
```

How do I delete an element from an array at a specified index but not perform the operation in place?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can duplicate array and remove element from this duplicate. Use `tap` to return array, but not a deleted element.

```
2.3.3 :018 > a = ["a", "b", "c"]
 => ["a", "b", "c"] 
2.3.3 :019 > b = a.dup.tap{|i| i.delete_at(0)}
 => ["b", "c"] 
2.3.3 :020 > b
 => ["b", "c"]
```

Another way is to use `reject` with `with_index`:

```
2.3.3 :042 > b = a.reject.with_index{|v, i| i == 0 }
 => ["b", "c"] 
2.3.3 :043 > b
 => ["b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You wish to create a new array which is the same as a given array less the element at a given index.

You could use [Array#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) (aka [Array#slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-slice)) and [Array#concat](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-concat).

```
def copy_wo_element(arr, index_to_exclude)
  arr[0,index_to_exclude].concat(arr[index_to_exclude+1..-1])
end

arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
copy_wo_element(arr, 0)
  #=> [2, 3, 4, 5] 
copy_wo_element(arr, 1)
  #=> [1, 3, 4, 5] 
copy_wo_element(arr, 2)
  #=> [1, 2, 4, 5] 
copy_wo_element(arr, 3)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 5] 
copy_wo_element(arr, 4)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You could instead write

```
arr[0,index_to_exclude] + arr[index_to_exclude+1..-1]
```

but the use of `concat` avoids the creation of the temporary array `arr[index_to_exclude+1..-1]`.